# Generate Julia Set Escape values for a circle with a radius of 2 in c++

Tags: c++

I have to generate escape values for a circle with a radius of 2 to for a Julia set. Here is my code, I am generating values but they are way off from what they should be. What am I doing wrong here?

```
int main() {
double width = 5;
double height = 5;
double a = .271;
double b = .314;
double it = 9;
string name = Julia.txt
myfile.open(name);
double new_x = 4 / (width-1);
double new_y = 4 / (height-1);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        double y0 = 2 - (y*new_y);
        double x0 = -2 + (x*new_x);
        for (double i = 0; i < it; i++) {
            new_x = x0;
            new_y = y0;
            x0 = (new_x*new_x - (new_y*new_y)) + a;
            y0 = (2 * new_x*new_y) + b;
            if (((x0 * x0) + (y0 * y0)) > 4) {
                myfile << x0, y0; 
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
myfile.close(); 
return 0;
}
```

it should write

```
5 5 9
0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 7 1 0 
0 2 9 2 0 
0 1 7 2 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

to the file but instead I am getting

```
0.271-7.68612.271-15.68696.271-39.6861020.27-127.68616896.3-519.6864.2710.31412.271-15.686100.2710.3141020.27-127.68616900.30.3140.271-7.68612.27116.31464.271-119.686924.271640.31416416.3-5719.69-4091.73256.314-37619.7-1551.69-33630011600.3-3.03354e+06-111488-2.72733e+071.35824e+06-4.36726e+08-83591.7-6.98729e+09668720-1.11798e+11-6.68724e+06-1.78876e+128.55965e+07-2.86202e+13-1.39094e+09
```

Comment: Suggestion: While you are testing remove all the user input. It's just going to slow you down to have to type stuff in all the time. Plus when testing you want to run the same sets over and over looking for changes in the output as you fix bugs, so not only are you typing stuff in all the time, you're typing the same stuff in over and over. Plus if your program is hard-coded with the values you use to trigger your failure case it make it really, really easy for folk out here on the Internet to run exactly what you're running and help you out.

Comment: Looking over the code, it is extremely unlikely you want to use the the comma operator here: `myfile << x0, y0;`

Comment: I changed the format to add specific values @user4581301

Comment: Other than printing the values wrong, there is nothing in your code that stands out as misuse of C++. I recommend you fire up a debugger and step through your code, whilst checking intermidiate values of all variables. That will uncover math or logic erros.

Comment: Can you create a minimal but working example?
This one has no headers and misses " for strings.